# Django Multiple Databases for Different Users

Tags: python, django, database

I'm wondering if it's possible to use multiple databases for different users in the same app?

I've read about the [multiple database documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#:%7E:text=Django%27s%20admin%20doesn%27t%20have,a%20specific%20database%20for%20content.) and searched a lot online but could'nt found any tutorial for it.

**Is there any way to use different databases for different users in the same app ?**

Comment: Not tried it, but have you seen the idea of multitenancy? Check out https://www.section.io/engineering-education/implement-multitenancy-with-multiple-databases-in-django/

Comment: Thanks Andy, that sounds interesting. Let me check it out for a while. Have a good one !